# Control of access to starting another android apps, to user data and etc

Tags: android, security, controls, request

I develop Android app which has next work scenario:

1. User sets a list of apps and password.
2. If application from this list will start, then shown request of password.
3. If the password is incorrect, then the access is not allowed.
4. If the password is correct - the application runs.

How to implement such functionality?
Does anyone knows similar open source projects? There are such applications in the Andoid Market, but I didn't found their sources.

And another question. Is it possible to control the access of applications to the Internet, to sending SMS, to user data and etc.?
Suppose some kind of app during its work requests access to the Internet - on the screen again displays a warning requesting for the password. The correct input - access to a resource is open, the wrong - the application continues to work, but without giving him the required data.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Comment: i am developing app like yours and i am stuck in int.
what did you use to make it work

Comment: Yes, i made it works. I made only password protection of app's launching. But if you want to control access to the internet, sms sending, etc., then you need root access to device. I did not research this way. If you interested in the password protectection then I'll write an answer about it tomorrow or the day after tomorrow.